# RHEL mysql cannot connect through the socket, permissions and locations are set properly, curious about the reasons

Tags: mysql, linux

I had a problem over the weekend. MySQL started giving "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'" Error over the weekend.

As suggested, I checked the location of the socket file, and it was in the right spot.

Then I checked the permission of the folders, and they were set to 0755.

Then I checked the disk space and there was plenty of it.

Then I performed a graceful server restart. That was what solved the problem.

My question, with these given, what can be the cause for this issue? This is our production server and I need to do due diligence an get to the root of this to prevent this from happening.

EDIT:

I am not attempting to resolve the issue, I am attempting to investigate the cause.

my.cnf has this set:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Thank you.

Comment: Might be an SELinux related issue. Try to investigate this.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg SElinux is disabled on this box.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I ran into this issue, I was able to get around it by setting the host parameter (`-h127.0.0.1`).

I'm not sure why it worked though, or rather, I'm not sure which specific configuration issues lead to it. Sometimes there can be different mysql.sock files at the same time, or in unexpected places (for example, on my last work machine I accidentally had three instances in different directories).

Comment: We have one instance running. And the socket file was exactly where it claimed it couldn't establish connection through.

Comment: The server was using unix socket connection, instead of the tcp. I'm pretty sure -h127.0.0.1 would work. Issue is that none of the apps on the server use tcp to connect, they use the socket instead.